# Error about compass when trying to run 'assetic:dump'

Tags: symfony, compass-sass

I'm getting the error below when i try to run : `php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev --no-debug`.

I don't know if it is related or not.

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                                  
  An error occurred while running:                                                                                     
  '/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/local/bin/compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--images-dir' '/home/tirengarfio/workspace/canalones/app  
  /../web/images' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compassYNg6JH' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compasssdSsQF.  
  scss'                                                                                                                

  Error Output:                                                                                                        
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find compass (>= 0) amongst [sass-3.2.5] (G  
  em::LoadError)                                                                                                       
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'                                                    
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'                                                                  
    from /usr/local/bin/compass:18:in `<main>'                                                                          


  Input:                                                                                                               
  @import "compass/css3";                                                                                              
  @import "compass/utilities";                                                                                         

  $naranja: #FF6600;                                                                                                   
  $blanco: #FFFFFF;                                                                                                    
  $verde_oscuro: #006666;                                                                                              
  $verde_claro: #009900;                                                                                               

  #content_center {                                                                                                    
  position: relative;                                                                                                  
      #bg {                                                                                                            
          /*background: url('/bundles/canalonesfrontend/images/bg_gris_puntos.png');*/                                 
          background: url('/bundles/canalonesfrontend/images/otis_redding.png');                                       
          width: 800px;                                                                                                
          height: 330px;                                                                                               
          position: absolute;                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                                
      .slides_container {                                                                                              
          width:570px;                                                                                                 
          height:270px;                                                                                                
          margin: 0 auto;                                                                                              
          position: absolute;                                                                                          
          z-index: 10;                                                                                                 
          div {                                                                                                        
          margin-top: 25px;                                                                                            
             width:570px;                                                                                              
             height:270px;                                                                                             
             display:block;                                                                                            
         }                                                                                                             
      }                                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                                    


  #container_info                                                                                                      
  {                                                                                                                    
     .item_info {                                                                                                      
         background: $naranja;                                                                                         
         width: 192px;                                                                                                 
         height: 250px;                                                                                                
         float: left;                                                                                                  
         margin: 15px;                                                                                                 
         padding: 10px 19px;                                                                                           
         border: 3px solid orange;                                                                                     
         @include border-radius(14px);                                                                                 
         .title {                                                                                                      
             color: $blanco;                                                                                           
             margin: 9px 0;                                                                                            
         }                                                                                                             
         .content {                                                                                                    
         }                                                                                                             
     }                                                                                                                 
  }
```

NOTE: one guy is having [here](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes) the same problem some time ago, and other person replies that he should make compass work as standalone, but.. any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Compass:

```
gem install compass
```

Rather than installing Compass manually, consider using Bundler][1](http://gembundler.com/) for managing dependencies for your project.

### UPD 2013-03-29

> I installed compass, it seems it was not installed even if i installed and work with it one month ago. Anyway the error is the same I mention in my question.. When I run 'compass create sass test' there is no error..

1) Please check whether Compass is correctly configured in Symfony. You can use this beautiful guide as a reference:

http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Sass-Compass-Assetic-In-Ten-Minutes

2) Please check the paths to `ruby` and `compass` executables with the `which` command and compare them with the paths from the beginning of the error output.

Note that you should run `which` as a user running your application, for example:

```
sudo -iu www-data which ruby
sudo -iu www-data which compass
```

Comment: I installed compass, it seems it was not installed even if i installed and work with it one month ago. Anyway the error is the same I mention in my question.. When I run 'compass create sass test' there is no error..

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of things you should check. Please try that and reply back!

Answer (score 0):

You can normally compile compass projects separately pretty easily. Just run

```
compass compile /path/to/project
```

make sure you have the gem installed.